# Ember-Data - Access Query-Params within model

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection, ember-data

```
{
  "name": "buchix",
  "dependencies": {
    "handlebars": "2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "ember": "1.9",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.12",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.7",
    "loader.js": "stefanpenner/loader.js#1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "stefanpenner/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader#0.0.4",
    "ember-load-initializers": "stefanpenner/ember-load-initializers#0.0.2",
    "ember-qunit": "0.1.8",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.4",
    "qunit": "~1.15.0",
    "ember-simple-auth": "~0.7.1",
    "momentjs": "~2.8.4",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.1"
  }
}
```

I have a simple app with a model "Person" and a model "week" (1:n relation).

The model "person" has a computed property "currentWeek" which returns the current week (filtering by attributes like "year" and "calendarWeek"). Everything works fine here.
The problem is, when the query-params of my controller (calendarWeek, year) changes, i need this property to recompute. But is can't access the query-params in my model like this

```
currentWeek: function() {
    var self = this;
    var weeks = this.get('weeks').filter(function(week) {
      return week.get('kw') === 50 && week.get('year') === 2014;
    });
    return weeks.objectAt(0);
}.property('kw', 'year'),
```

How can i inject the query-params into my ember-data-model so i can recompute the property on each query-param change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. I tried to put the logic into the model. But i have to put it into a controller. My PersonController of type ArrayController should specify an ItemController like so.

```
App.PersonsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'person'
});

App.PersongController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  currentWeek: function() {

    var self = this;
    var weeks = this.get('weeks').filter(function(week) {
      return week.get('kw') === 50 && week.get('year') === 2014;
    });
    return weeks.objectAt(0);

  }.property('kw', 'year')
});
```

Now i can access 'kw' and 'year' via dependency injection for example.